# Why I can't ask my question from the correct community?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

**Update2:** When I asked this question I was really unfamiliar with the community, Tool recommendation is opinion based that's why my question would not fit to SO.

Anyway I leave this question here maybe it is gonna be useful for somebody.

---

So here is my problem/point of view:

I have a question like: "which JavaScript library should I use for this problem?" The correct place for that question is [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

However, there is no community there. I just looked around and it is full of unanswered questions. Meanwhile, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) has a strong community, with experienced developers who are able to help me in less then a minute.

I understand the purpose of different sites for different topic, but this is counterproductive.

**Update:**
I am able to write the question in a good format on Stack Overflow or Code Review (posting some code how I do right now, and asking help), but this is a workaround to an existing problem. I just not sure why we should post questions which are related to programming in another community.

Comment: As a note... if you ask off topic questions on SO, repeatedly, you are likely to lose your ability to post there at all. Please, use the correct site.

Comment: I didn't, and I did my homework look around and end up with Software Recommendations site, and it is disappointing.  1st of all: it was hard to find, I gonna bookmark it, and look on it time to time, maybe I can help ppl. there. 2nd: It is useless right now It can't fulfill there purpose without community. maybe there are few ppl. on SO who are happy to help there, but I am sure 99% of the ppl. don't know that site is exist. And asking "which video player should I use" is not the same about: "I have this program ruing from 8 years, I want to change one dependency what you guys suggest?"

Comment: What do you mean that "there is no community there"? According to https://stackexchange.com/sites it has 28K users.

Comment: Users are not your research assistants.  Doesn't it seem a little lazy to try to make someone else do your work for you?

Comment: So we have one site that doesn't allow these kinds of questions that's very popular. Over here we have another site that is all about them, that nobody goes to. Possibly that tells us something about the viability of these questions on Stack Exchange.

Comment: SR... kinda stinks, anyhow :/ You'd be much better served answering your own question by making small prototypes using different frameworks, in the long run. Not the answer you were looking for, but that's what I've found works best for me (although it does make my workload bigger).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hail from some of the smaller sites on Stack Exchange - certainly in relation to Stack Overflow, and probably compared to the biggest computer-related sites. Some of the sites I frequent and/or moderate are ghost towns in comparison; others are busy enough for me but nowhere near the mad levels of activity on SO.

Transitioning to these communities from larger sites can entail a bit of a culture shock, I'm sure. I've seen the same reaction from other SO users who ask something on, say, [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/), and are amazed at how few questions we get each day. It takes some adapting to. Likewise, I'm constantly blown away by the sheer *size* of Stack Overflow, and the amount of content that flows through it.

Stack Exchange was built around programmers, and it continues to remain focused on programmers, though it now serves [cooks](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), [pilots](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/), [physicists](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), [gardeners](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/), and more. But it attracts more programmers than any of these other groups, and so you simply have fewer cooks and pilots and physicists and gardeners than programmers. Heck, many of the people who use the smaller sites aren't professionals, but enthusiasts.

I hope that in the future things might change a bit - that the rest of the network will grow and soon become well-known all on its own for the other topics it hosts. I hope that it brings more people like me, who come in knowing nothing about programming and at first don't use the network for anything programming-related.

Software Recs is, yes, quite computer-related. But it still isn't the main feature of the network. It's not what most people come for. That's Stack Overflow.

For now we have to wait a little bit on many of the smaller sites. Take your time and have a little patience. I promise you it will pay off.

---

Now you might say, "Well, there are people on Stack Overflow who can cook some delicious penne or fly a 747 or predict a specific particle decay chain or grow a rather nice bunch of petunias. Why can't I ask them about those specific subjects . . . on Stack Overflow?"

Well, we have different sites for a couple reasons:

- **Organization.** It's much easier to keep track of all of the cooking questions if you have a dedicated site for it.
- **The right audience.** If you're on Stack Overflow, you might not care about cooking; if you ask on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), you *know* the people reading your question care about cooking. This also means that potential answerers see questions they're more likely to care about.
- **Separation is going to happen anyway.** Groups that care about these completely unrelated topics will form anyway, and the same subset of users will often interact with one another on questions about those topics. A community within a community forms; it's large enough that it should have its own site.

Comment: Please check my comment under the main question. It is retaliated to your edit. I got answers about why should I ask unrelated questions in different sites, i got it. My original question as about why I need to ask software programming related questions, about programming problems. On a site what made for: "what torrent clients you are suggest?" etc type of questions.

Comment: @Peter don't rely on people to dig through comments; if something is important, edit it into the question so people will see it.

Answer (score 25):

I have a problem for you.

I really want a sandwich.  The correct place to get that sandwich is a diner down the street, but the place is always empty and has horrible customer service.  There's a car wash across the street, and I really like it, they have good prices, it's well serviced, and they're always open when I'm hungry.  But whenever I go to the car wash and ask them for a sandwich they tell me that they don't sell sandwiches, they just wash cars.  I understand that different places sell different things, but this is counterproductive.

---

At the end of the day, SO isn't a place for software recommendations.  People go there because they want to answer (or find answers to) specific, practical, objective programming problems, not to provide or get software recommendations.  People looking to provide or seek out software recommendations go to Software Recommendations.  That more people are interested in answering practical programming problems than software recommendations doesn't make asking people uninterested in software recommendations to recommend software.

Comment: Not sure that's the best metaphor, a car wash that sells sandwiches isn't that ridiculous—it could be a great way to diversify ;)

Comment: the example is not good, because stackoverflow  community able to answer the question, and there is a good chance to somebody will, (there are lots of this type of questions there from the old times)

Comment: @Helmar A site that answers programming questions also providing software recommendations isn't ridiculous either (many other QA sites, besides SO, allow them), but this particular programming QA site doesn't answer software recommendations, just like certain car washes don't sell sandwiches.

Comment: @Peter So you think that no one at a car wash is able to make a sandwich?  Do you really think making sandwiches is *that* hard?  They're *capable* of doing it, but that business has simply made a decision about what goods and services they do and don't provide, and what you want isn't one that they provide.

Comment: To take your example a step further, say you go to the car wash's management and ask why you can't buy a sandwich there, you might get a strange metaphor about programming Q&A sites and software recommendation Q&A sites... (Or, more likely, they laugh you off the property.)

Comment: @Servy you  example would be good if I my question would be not related to programming, like: "why i can't ask question about astrology on stack overflow because there are some ppl who know astrology there?"

Comment: @Peter Alright, say you want a sandwich. There's a diner down the street that sells them, but that is always empty and has bad reviews. Instead, you go to a pizza place (one that sells _only_ pizza) and ask for a sandwich. After all, they are a restaurant. They have bread, cheese, and meat. Surely they can make you a sandwich! But they turn you away because they do not sell sandwiches. Both places sell food, you just want to buy _specific_ food from _this_ location that doesn't sell it.

Comment: You surely will have a sandwich in six to eight weeks :)